# Get notified of failed SSH login attempts on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, security

I want to enable SSH on my Mac, but I want to be notified when someone tries to log in.

I'm running on a non-default port, so attempts should be rare.

I'm currently running a growl notification in `.profile`, but I'm not sure that is fool-proof, and I'd rather have email.

```
lgn=`who | grep "("`
if [ -n "$lgn" ]; then
    growlnotify login -m $lgn
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specific to Mountain Lion (10.8):

At a general level, instead of using the `who` command, you could have a daemon monitor `/var/log/system.log`.

Specifically, look for these kinds of messages:

```
Jan 22 01:06:26 hostname sshd[1787]: input_userauth_request: invalid user foo [preauth]
Jan 22 01:06:58 hostname sshd[1794]: error: PAM: authentication error for root from 1.2.3.4 via 5.6.7.8
```

I realize this is an old question, but I'm also looking for a more concrete (and perhaps ready-made) solution to this; were you (OP) able to find a satisfying answer?

As an aside, it might be more beneficial asking at [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Saying that attempts will be rare because you changed the port, means that most probably script kiddies will be "tricked" by this. Somebody will first use a program like [NMap](http://nmap.org/) to scan your machine for open ports and afterwards try to connect to those.

Anyway, getting back to your question, you might want to first check these questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696494/can-os-x-lion-server-send-an-email-when-a-user-connects-via-ssh-or-vpn) and [Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45688/getting-notified-when-someone-logs-into-a-server-using-ssh-or-remote-desktop), which present interesting solution to your problem.